# Java returns error message for a jar that is not included in the program

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, jxl

Somehow, if I create a new java project with an almost empty class, Java returns the following error message:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at jxl.biff.drawing.PNGReader.main(PNGReader.java:141)
```

The jExcel api (jxl) is not included in the program and neither the .jar file.

The program code is as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Good morning");

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you run your program ?

Comment: You seem to be starting the wrong program, as the bottom line of the stack trace mentions the main() method of class `jxl.biff.drawing.PNGReader` instead of your Main class.

Comment: @Berger: I am using Eclipse

Comment: @Ralf Kleberhoff: You were right, somehow, my Main class was not selected as default, even though I closed all other classes and restarted Eclipse. Thank a lot!